# Angular Bootstrap Close an opened navbar when clicking outside (As dropdown)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-bootstrap

I'm using Angular Bootstrap in my application. I'm using 2 navbar in that. it is working properly for me and is responsive too. What I want to do is make the navbar-toggle button as dropdown instead of coming and staying there.

Here is what I tried http://plnkr.co/edit/CMxdQnSWCiDmOt9NWngJ?p=preview

I created a directive

```
app.directive('navDropdown', function ($parse, $document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var fn = $parse(attr.navDropdown);
            $document.bind('click', clickOutsideHandler);
            element.bind('remove', function () {
                $document.unbind('click', clickOutsideHandler);
            });
            function clickOutsideHandler(event) {
                var clickover = $(event.target);
                var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse in");
                if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
                    // $("button.navbar-toggle").click();
                    $(".navbar .navbar-collapse").removeClass("in");
                    scope.navCollapsed = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And I used the directive in both `nav` elements. But it's not working properly.

First time, it may work properly. But if you click outside and then try to open menu, you will need to click the button twice. Sometimes that also not working.

How can I solve it?

I need to close all nav and drop down menus when we click outside. If we click inside any nav, close all except the current.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your off click problem, I have this nice directive:

```
  app.directive('offClick', ['$document', '$timeout', function ($document, $timeout) {

     function targetInFilter(target, filter) {
        if (!target || !filter) return false;
        var elms = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(filter));
        var elmsLen = elms.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < elmsLen; ++i)
           if (elms[i].contains(target)) return true;
        return false;
     }

     return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           offClick: '&',
           offClickIf: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {

           if (attr.offClickIf) {
              scope.$watch(scope.offClickIf, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                 if (newVal && !oldVal) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                       $document.on('click', handler);
                    });
                 } else if (!newVal) {
                    $document.off('click', handler);
                 }
              }
              );
           } else {
              $document.on('click', handler);
           }

           scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
              $document.off('click', handler);
           });

           function handler(event) {
              // This filters out artificial click events. Example: If you hit enter on a form to submit it, an
              // artificial click event gets triggered on the form's submit button.
              if (event.pageX == 0 && event.pageY == 0) return;

              var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
              if (!(elm[0].contains(target) || targetInFilter(target, attr.offClickFilter))) {
                 scope.$apply(scope.offClick());
              }
           }
        }
     };
  }]);
```

on your html you can use like this:

```
<div id="dvTravelers" ng-click="clickMenuTravelers()" off-click="clickMenuTravelers()" off-click-filter="#dvAddTravelersModal" off-click-if="menuVarOpen">
```

then you can set your logic inside the functions on click event inside and outiside